# Execution Timeout Expired Azure Logic App

Tags: timeout, gateway

We have an excessively complex stored procedure in SQL Server (which I did not write and cannot change).

I created an Azure logic app, using a "Recurrence" (not a "Sliding Window") trigger, with an "Execute stored procedure (V2)" action, and set the "frequency" to run daily at 22:00 (10pm).

But, I try running it manually just to test it (Run Trigger).
It runs for between 9 1/2 and 10 1/2 minutes, then fails with a "Bad Gateway" and "Error 504" and "Timeout Expired" error (see JSON at bottom):

How do I increase the timeout? Is there a simple setting buried in Azure that I'm missing?

I never specified any gateway, and another, much simpler stored procedure with no gateway specification executed fine.

And lastly, I am an Azure neophyte.

Thank you.

{
"error": {
"code": 504,
"source": "logic-apis-eastus2.azure-apim.net",
"clientRequestId": "{I removed the client request Id before posting this}",
"message": "BadGateway",
"innerError": {
"status": 504,
"message": "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.\r\nclientRequestId: {I removed the client request Id before posting this}",
"error": {
"message": "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."
},
"source": "sql-eus2.azconn-eus2.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
}